# What are the exercises that increases Stamina and Endurance of the body?

Tags: stamina

I am curious to know what kind or what forms of exercises increases stamina.Is it Running,Body building,swimming or else?

Comment: Well any kind of exercise increases your 'stamina', so your question is rather vague. Do you have a specific purpose or a goal you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aerobic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerobic_exercise) exercise will increase your endurance. (I'm assuming you mean the same thing by stamina and endurance.)

Aerobic exercise would include exercises like distance running, swimming, and biking. Some guidelines for the target heart rate for aerobic exercise are in [this chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Exercise_zones.png):

[image]

Comment: I've seen this image before. Quote: "For the Weight control zone (which IMHO is the worst zone to work out if you're trying to lose fat)"... See this answer http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/how-do-i-workout-my-heart-rate-zones-for-training